# NSView viewDidMoveToSuperview not called

Tags: cocoa

I have a storyboard app, with a simple `NSView` subclass set in a `NSViewController`. In an effort, to match the width of a `NSTextContainer` to the views width, I tried setting it in `func viewDidMoveToSuperview()` - thinking at this point, the view bounds would be set. But, this function is never called. `func viewWillMove(toSuperview newSuperview: NSView?)` is not called either.

Are there any circumstances when these functions are not called (or when can I expect them to be called)?

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: RMTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}

class RMTextView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {
    public var textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager!
    public var textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage!
    public var textContainer: NSTextContainer!
    internal var fragmentLayerMap: NSMapTable<NSTextLayoutFragment, CALayer>!

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        wantsLayer = true
        contentLayer = CALayer()
        layer?.addSublayer(contentLayer)

        fragmentLayerMap = .weakToWeakObjects()

        textContentStorage = NSTextContentStorage()
        textContainer = NSTextContainer(containerSize: NSSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textLayoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
        textLayoutManager.textContainer = textContainer
        textContentStorage.addTextLayoutManager(textLayoutManager)

        textLayoutManager.textViewportLayoutController.delegate = self

        setSelectedRange(NSTextRange(location: textContentStorage.documentRange.location))
    }

    override func viewDidMoveToSuperview() {
        // This is never called
        print("viewDidMoveToSuperview")
    }

    override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        // Is there a better place to set the textContainer size to match the view bounds
        if superview != nil {
            textContainer.size = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. `func viewDidMoveToWindow()` is called and I am able to set the textcontainer size in there. Is there a better place to do this?

Thanks

Edit: To be clearer, my custom view `RMTextView` is setup as a subview in my Storyboard's `ViewController` scene. `ViewController->View->RMTextView`

Edit2: Added some relevant code bits

Edit3: Sample project on github - https://github.com/georgemp/CocoaViewLifecycle

Comment: Does the view have a superview or is it the contentview of a window? What are you trying to accomplish? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: The view does have a superview. The superview is attached to the window. I just want to know under what circumstances these methods are called. The documentation just says that it's called when the superview changes. So, I was expecting it to be called when it's attached to the superview

Comment: Have added a minimal github project as well (it doesn't have the TextKit bits, but, shows my issue with view lifecycle methods)

Comment: Apparently the view doesn't move to a superview because it is already in there. Is the view (or window) resizable?

Comment: The window is resizable, and the view does resize along with the window. So, I guess what you are saying is that when it is unarchived from the .storyboard, it's already installed in the parent view? But, it is later added to window (which causes `viewDidMoveToWindow` to be called)?

Comment: Yes. Do you adjust the size of the text container when the view resizes? Have you tried overriding `layout()`?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I replace the root view in ViewController to be a NSScrollView (so that the hierarchy is NSScrollView->NSClipView->RMTextView), then the `viewDidMoveToSuperview()` method is called. This is entirely contained in storyboard as well.

Overriding layout() works fine